# How do we set 'aes' argument in 'ggplot'?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes

What is meaning of `aes(x=y)` here?

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(diamonds, mapping = aes(x=y))+geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5)
```

Comment: It means that the x axis is mapping the "y" variable from dataframe "diamonds".  Odd choice of names, but nonetheless programmatically valid.

Comment: What that specifically means is that the column named `y` in that data frame will be mapped to the x-axis in plotting. Otherwise it's a broad question and I think you'd be served better by tutorials. `ggplot2` has pretty extensive documentation that I'd recommend reading through, and the doc site links to [this chapter](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html) of R for Data Science all about it

Comment: @camille , I overlooked that y is a column name in the dataset. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Nicolás Velásquez, Thank you for help. I will be careful in future about these types of mistakes.